# Do you have trouble thinking wiki when responding to answers?

Tags: discussion, edits

I edit a fair amount of questions to improve them -- mostly formatting, but some spelling and grammar.  Invariably, though I find myself commenting on answers instead of editing them to improve them.  Anyone else notice this same behavioral quirk?  I just seem to have a hard time changing someone's answer even if I think I can improve it.  I've done it a couple of times, but most of the time I leave a comment rather than make a fix.

Answer (score 4):

If it is grammatical or clarification changes, I *always* edit.

If there is an error in understanding or the actual information contained in the post, I will *always* comment. I am not comfortable changing/editing the original meaning of a post. I would rather leave that to the original author.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the voting system creates a strong sense of ownership which percolates even to the wiki mode. I'm wary to change content or even to add to it as well, just like rcar and tvanfosson.

Now, I think this is not the best way to proceed and that only us editors can change this trend through willpower and careful editing. This is, only improve, never offend or change everything without leaving a trace.

Answer (score 2):

No. I'll happily jump in and edit an answer if there's a problem and i have the energy...

...but i **am** disgustingly lazy, so sometimes i'll just leave comments 'cause it's easier than re-writing the whole answer. And if it comes down to being a matter of taste (e.g. coding style rather than an actual error), i'll tend to leave a comment rather than jumping in and adjusting it to fit my preferences.